# How can i vertical-align multiple line content?

Tags: css, html, alignment, vertical-alignment

I have three divs that have multiple line content wrapped in an anchor. I tried using display:table-cell or top:50% and margin-top:50% but no effect.
Again i want the .box_content to be centered in .box_item.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/A453K/) is my code:

```
<div id="boxes_onze">
   <a href="#">
       <div class="box_item">
        <div class="box_content">Equity Funds</div>
       </div>
   </a>
   <a href="#">
      <div class="box_item">
        <div class="box_content">Fixed Income Funds</div>
      </div>
   </a>
   <a href="#">
      <div class="box_item">
        <div class="box_content">Mixed Funds</div>
      </div>
   </a>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
#boxes_onze{width:100%; margin-top:50px;}
#boxes_onze a{text-decoration:none; color:#3c9ccc; font-size:24px; font-family:HelveticaNeueTh; line-height: 24px;}
#boxes_onze .box_item{width:33%; margin-right:1px; height:77px; display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;   background:lightblue; url(imagini/arrow_fondsen.png); position:relative; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position: 95% center;}
#boxes_onze .box_item .box_content{width:136px; margin-left:13px;}
div{float:left;}
```

Comment: @GMR please don't remove code, this is not acceptable. (You have changed `background:lightblue; url(imagini/arrow_fondsen.png);` to `background:#ADD8E6;`)

Comment: i don't understand the goal, which part of the content should be vertical aligned in what way?

Comment: you want the `.box_content` to be centered in `.box_item`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this technique a lot:

CSS:

```
.valign-content:before { content : ''; display : inline-block; width : 0; height : 100%; vertical-align : middle; }

.valign-content>* { vertical-align : middle; display : inline-block; }
```

Add the class to an element and all the first level children will be vertical aligned.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/pavloschris/A453K/2/

Comment: @Mr_Green I Don't know what you mean by 'hack', but I suppose it isn't. It's more like a 'workaround' I suppose.